# Boot failure in wifi module

Tags: stm32, modem

I am using a redpine rs9113 WiFi module in my device functioning with stm32l476 micro controller. Spi is used for the communication with the modem. While communicating with the modem, it constantly says boot failure. Is it because the WiFi module is not getting enough current to wake up. If yes, what is the minimum requirement?

Comment: *If yes, what is the minimum requirement?* I would need to look into the **datasheet** to find the value, instead of me doing that, start by doing that yourself.

Comment: Your question is XY problem -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. You should firstly look at the datasheet.